# Importing Excel CSV with PHP that has special characters

Tags: php, excel, csv, character-encoding, fgetcsv

I'm attempting to import a csv in php that is saved as a csv through Microsoft Excel. I have attempted using both fopen and fgetcsv with the same issue.

I have noticed through debugging that excel doesn't save a charset on the file when exporting as a csv, therefor php is assuming that the file is ascii and is attempting to drop / convert any non ascii characters (Ex: é, î, è) to boolean.

What is the best way to import a csv that has non ascii characters without having to drop the non ascii characters?

---------- EDIT --------------

```
<?php
    try{
         ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
         $file = $_FILES['file'] ['tmp_name'];

         $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');

         while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
             foreach ($data as $d) {
                 Log::info($d);
             }
         }
         fclose($handle);
     }catch(\Exception $e){
         abort(500, $e->getMessage());
     }
```

Then using the same function as above ( I took out some of the extra code so I'm not 100% sure this code is functioning ) any characters that are not in ASCII are being converted to boolean, well attempted to anyways, php (laravel) errors out because boolean is not of the type _toString for the json_encode on the response object.

Comment: I would suggest looking into https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: @HalfCrazed I will check it out. Have you by chance used this library before, if so how is it?

Comment: Yes, I've used it - works really well for us!

Comment: @HalfCrazed Thank you for suggesting that library for me, I've finally gotten around to using it and it uses the same function I was using so it is unfortunately still continuing with the same bug. Do you have any other libraries you've used that you could recommend?

Comment: Can you post an example of what's going on/what you're doing/what you're trying to do?

Comment: @HalfCrazed No problem, I've added an edit to the original question :)

Comment: I'm not seeing where you're using the PHPExcel library. Perhaps, if you are using the library, you need to set the character set (and yes, Excel does have character set settings) via `$objReader->setInputEncoding('');` (see http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/ouardisoft/PHPExcel/source-class-PHPExcel_Reader_CSV.html#175-185) - Excel is saved in, by default, UTF-8... so if there's a different charset that's being used, you'll need to convert it (`iconv`, for example)